# Using .strip_tags($this->item->introtext). with a macro

Tags: joomla, strip-tags

I'm using [RokCandy](http://www.rockettheme.com/extensions-joomla/rokcandy) macro extension. This extension creates complex HTML codes from simple texts, so it's easier to give regular formats to some objects.

The problem is that in the head of every article I have a code for making Facebook OG work:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="'.strip_tags($this->item->introtext).'"/>
```

Well, now the problem: as the macro makes the trick AFTER reading printing the META description, HTML tags are not stripped out, because they're inserted after. So I have lot's of iframes, objects and tables inserted in the head of the page, making the format a total mess.

I've asked to the RokCandy creators, but there's no answer yet. Do you know of an effective way to make all tags stripped out?

Thanks

---

I edit:

---

I have found a bad solution (strings are deleted, but code is quite messy):

```
$data= $this->item->introtext;
$new_data = str_replace  ("[", "", $data);
```

And then:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="'.strip_tags($new_data).'"/>
```

The tweak is that I delete the [ character, that was making the macro work. But I can't delete the code inside it (for example: [youtube]).

Answer (score 0):

Making it a little bit better:

```
$doc =& JFactory::getDocument();
$data= $this->item->introtext;
$bideogabe = str_replace  ("[youtube]", "http://youtu.be/", $data);
$bestelakoak = array("[/youtube]", "[", "]");
$new_data = str_replace ($bestelakoak, "", $bideogabe);
```

And then:

```
<meta property="og:description" content="'.strip_tags($new_data).'"/>
```